# Consulta PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela vendas (id, data, loja, cliente, valor), qual o comando SQL para me retornar os 3 maiores clientes(maior valor) de cada loja. Alguém sabe?

Comment: Pesquise por window function na documentação. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 1):

Para solução dos problemas segui os seguintes passos:

1.Obtido total de vendas por cliente e loja

```
SELECT  loja,
        cliente,
        sum(valor) AS total_vendas
FROM vendas
GROUP BY cliente,
         loja
ORDER BY loja,
         sum(valor) DESC
```

2.Realizada a classificação dos clientes por loja

```
...
row_number() OVER ( 
      PARTITION BY loja
      ORDER BY total_vendas DESC 
) AS rank
....
```

3.Exibição dos top 3 clientes com maior venda por loja

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT *,
           row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY loja
                              ORDER BY total_vendas DESC ) AS rank
   FROM
     ( SELECT loja,
              cliente,
              sum(valor) AS total_vendas
      FROM vendas
      GROUP BY cliente,
               loja
      ORDER BY loja,
               sum(valor) DESC ) AS total_vendas_cliente ) AS top_vendas_loja
WHERE rank <= 3
```

Se desejar exibir os top 5, top 10 basta alterar a condição do rank.